# In which of the following chemical compounds are the building blocks molecules?

Tags: molecules, covalent-compounds, salt

> In which of the following chemical compounds are the building blocks molecules?
>
> (A) $\ce{AgNO3}$
> (B) $\ce{HNO3}$
> (C) $\ce{KNO3}$
> (D) $\ce{NaNO3}$

(B) is the correct answer, but I have no idea why. Could you briefly explain why this is the correct answer?

Comment: Strange question, is this complete? as written in the book?

Comment: @GM: I agree. Yes, that's all information that's given in the book.

Comment: Can you give some more context, or tell us which book? The question as written does not make sense.

Comment: I highly doubt this is correctly copied from the textbook. It isn't even good English AFAIK.

Comment: @Jori: It's because I translated it in English. Again, that's all information that's given, nothing else. The question looks exactly the same as the one given in the book, the only difference is that this one is translated in English.

Comment: Would you tell us what the original text was (in the native language)? Maybe there was a translation error.

Comment: I decided to call my chemistry teacher and he said that possible explanation could be that $HNO_{3}$ is a (nitric) acid, whereas e.g. $KNO_{3}$ is an ionic compound, therefore, it's buildnig blocks are not molecules, but ions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer B is correct because nitric acid is the only compound whose building blocks satisfy the [IUPAC Gold Book definition](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04002.html) of a molecule, a neutral (uncharged) entity consisting of at least 2 or more atoms. The building blocks of all other given compounds are atomic ($\ce{K+}$, $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Ag+}$) or molecular ions ($\ce{NO3-}$), which by their nature do not fulfill the requirement of being electrically neutral. Per definition, they are [molecular entities](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03986.html), i.e. distinct particles which can be identified as separate entities. This term is more general and also includes charged species like ions.